# How can I access a map key which contains an exclamation point?

Tags: javascript, api, json, reports-api

When I get the response of a request upon a report, the json looks like this :

```
"factMap" : {"2!0_0" : {      
  "aggregates" : [
    { "label" : "$16,000.01", "value" : 16000.010000000000218278728425502777099609375 },
    { "label" : "$16,000.01", "value" : 16000.010000000000218278728425502777099609375 },
    { "label" : "1", "value" : 1 } ],      
  "rows" : [ {        
    "dataCells" : [
      { "label" : "Acme - 200 Widgets", "value" : "006R00000023IDYIA2" },
      { "label" : "$16,000.01",          
        "value" : { "amount" : 16000.01, "currency" : null } },
      { "label" : "Word of mouth", "value" : "Word of mouth" },
      { "label" : "Need estimate", "value" : "Need estimate" },
      { "label" : "60%", "value" : 60},
      { "label" : "Q3-2015", "value" : "Q3-2015" },
      { "label" : "12", "value" : 12 },
      { "label" : "7/31/2015", "value" : "2015-07-31" },
      { "label" : "Fred Wiliamson", "value" : "005R0000000Hv5rIAC" },
      { "label" : "-", "value" : null } ]      
  } ]    
},    
"T!0" : {
  "aggregates" : [
    { "label" : "$32,021.01", "value" : 32021.00999999999839928932487964630126953125 },
    { "label" : "$16,010.51", "value" : 16010.504999999999199644662439823150634765625 },
    { "label" : "2", "value" : 2 } ],      
  "rows" : [ ]     
},   
 "T!T" : {
  "aggregates" : [

/* I want this value : 153042.01 */

    { "label" : "$153,042.01", "value" : 153042.01000000000931322574615478515625 },
    { "label" : "$25,507.00", "value" : 25507.00166666666700621135532855987548828125 },
    { "label" : "6", "value" : 6 } ],      
  "rows" : [ ]
```

I want to access to the first value after the "T!T".
I would have done it like this usually :

```
console.log(response.factMap.T!T.aggregates[0].value)
```

But I keep getting errors. I don't understand how there could be an exclamation mark (I read that exclamation marks are reserved characters in Json).

How can I access a map key which contains an exclamation point?

Comment: This isn't really a *Salesforce* question, per se, since it's pure Javascript. Anyway, I think it's a pretty easy fix. Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm quite new to coding and it was the first time I saw something like that so I assumed it was a Salesforce specificity.

Comment: Right. Yeah other systems can also return map keys which would not resolve to property names. Pretty generic. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get map keys using strings instead:

```
console.log(response.factMap['T!T'].aggregates[0].value);
```